# Regex value from input field dasn't work for date format

Tags: php, regex

I have some html

```
<td align="middle"><input id="_TEXTBOX_" type="text" value='2020-11-03 07:00:00' class="aukcja_textbox_disabled" readonly></td>

<td align="middle"><input id="_TEXTBOX_" type="text" value='2020-11-27 07:01:00' class="aukcja_textbox_disabled" readonly></td>

<td align="middle"><input id="_TEXTBOX_" type="text" value='WDK' size="8" class="aukcja_textbox_disabled" readonly></td>

<td align="middle"><input id="_TEXTBOX_" type="text" value='20' size="5" class="aukcja_textbox_disabled" readonly></td>

<td align="middle"><input id="_TEXTBOX_" type="text" value='20' size="3" class="aukcja_textbox_disabled" readonly></td>

<td align="middle"><input id="_TEXTBOX_" type="text" value='413' size="3" class="aukcja_textbox_disabled" readonly></td>
```

I wanna get every value from the inputs.
I do this by preg_match_all function.

```
preg_match_all('/<input id=\"_TEXTBOX_\" type=\"text\" value=\\\'([a-z,A-Z,0-9,:,-, ]*)\\\'/iU',$this->html,$matches);
```

But this code gets only values from four last input. It doesn't find two first with dates.
I've tried (.*) expression but it doesn't work too.

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this regex :

```
(?<=value=').*?(?=')
```

> (?<=value=') : mean leaded by **value='**
> (?=') : mean followed by '
> .*? : mean 0 or many character except \n and not greedy (mean will take first occurrence)

[**demo**](https://regexr.com/5h4fq)